@layers priority, cant understand the documentation
Have just one question
In the Mozilla @layer documentation I see the next one

Which means that
the lower priority has the user agent styles
Then - usual user styles
Then - styles in @layers
so if i have this code
@layer main {
  body {
   background: red;
  }
}

body {
 background: #1d1b1b;
}

Why I don't have red color? If styles in @layers has highest priority?
There is mistake in documentation? Or what i understand wrong?
Thanks
I tried to understand this visual priority screenshot

body { background: #1d1b1b; } is within the unlayered part at the top

So screenshot is incorrect?

no, the unlayered part is at the top so it has a higher specificity that's why you don't see red

@TemaniAfif So what would be an example of "Normal user declarations"? I guess OP was expecting their body { background: red } to fit in that category (I must admit I would too). IMO, not having more formal definitions of the categories looks bad for a doc, and this boxing in the diagram doesn't makes things easier to grasp...

Ps: looking at the specs it is specified what a normal declaration is: the ones that are not !important, and what an user declaration is: the ones that a web-browser's user will set on their own browser (e.g. custom themes). Then, the unnamed box is actually supposed to be labelled Normal author declarations, and then it makes sense, that's the ones we web-authors will set in our page's source code. Failing to even make that distinction is bad. I'll probably open an issue to have this clarified.

Indeed that diagram was a bit misleading (even to me, while I'm used to its nomenclature...) Thanks to you, it's been amended by MDN contributor OnkarRuikar, so that it now includes the proper "Normal author declarations" label on the box comprising both the "Unlayered" and the various "@layer" sub-boxes.
It is now a bit clearer that an "user declaration" is not the same as an "author declaration".
Along with the changes made in PR #36656, which will link to the definition of the various terms, it should be entirely clear that an "user declaration" here refers to the declarations made by the user of the web-browser (e.g. browser themes), and thus that what you as a web-author writes is actually part of the "author declarations".
So a rule like
body {
 background: #1d1b1b;
}

in a style sheet loaded from an HTML page is actually part of the "Unlayered" sub-box, i.e. it does have higher importance than the "@layer" ones.
